# Have there been significant performance improvements in TABLESAMPLE bernoulli since PostgreSQL 9.5?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-12

I have been testing queries with the same data in PostgreSQL 9.6.11 and PostgreSQL 12.3 using the `TABLESAMPLE bernoulli` clause. It seems PostgreSQL 12.3 executes the query about 25x faster than the old version. Before i dig into other performance optimizations, i tried looking into the documentation for the two versions for clues about performance improvements between v9.6 and v12.3. I didn't see any.

Does anyone know if there have been performance improvements to `TABLESAMPLE` in recent PostgreSQL versions?

Comment: Postgres 12 is in general faster then 9.6 maybe the enhanced parallelism is a reason for that. Did you compare the execution plans?

Comment: Yeah no difference in the execution plans (other than the estimated times)